# How to upgrade Mysql from 5.5 to 5.7?

Tags: debian, installation, mysql

I installed mysql just now using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Its version is:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

now how can I upgrade it to 5.7?

Answer (score 3):

[How to install MySQL server 5.6 or 5.7 on Debian 7 and 8](http://www.debiantutorials.com/install-mysql-server-5-6-debian-7-8/)

> **How to install MySQL server 5.6 or 5.7 on Debian 7 and 8**
>
> Debian provides MySQL server 5.5 with both wheezy and jessie but the
>   latest GA (Generally Available) releases are 5.6 and 5.7 with some
>   enhancements and added features, including support for InnoDB
>   Full-text search.
>
> Here’s how to install MySQL server 5.6 or 5.7 on Debian based Linux
>   distros (including wheezy, jessie and Ubuntu):
>
> 1. Update PGP keys
>      `apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net 5072E1F5`
> 2. Download the MySQL APT repository config tool (you can see more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/)
>
>    `wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb`
> 3. Install the MySQL APT repository config tool
>
>    `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb`
>
> You will be asked to select product and version that you want to
>   install. In the first step, select Server and next select either
>   mysql-5.6 or mysql-5.7. Then click Apply.
>
> 4. Update APT
>
>    `apt-get update`
> 5. Install the server
>
>    `apt-get install mysql-community-server`

Comment: the problem is that I have installed mysql server, what can I do? besides, what is the difference bewteen apt-get install  `mysql-community-server` and `apt-get install  mysql-server`